# can i use chi square for two ordinal variables

Tags: chi-squared-test, ordinal-data

I have two variables in my research survey, **Variable 1**(less than 6 hours,6-8 hours, more than 8 hours) and **variable 2**(not at all, several days, more than half the days, nearly everyday). I want to know if there's an association between them or not. Can I use chi square for these variables or should I use some other statistical test?

Comment: Why are these data categorized ? That's usually a very bad idea.

Comment: I am actually new to research and while designing the questionnaire I thought it was a good idea to have categorical variables rather than continuous variables but I am having a lot of problems during analysis.

Comment: Consider variable 1. You will treat a subject completely differently when they record 5:59:59, to another subject that recorded 6:00:00 even though they are essentially the same. Moreover, these 2 subjects will be treated the same as two that had 0:00:00, and the other 7:59:59, which are obviously very very different. This is one of the problems of categorizing a numeric variable. It's very bad.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this sir. I just have one confusion and I would be really grateful if you could answer that too. Variable 1 was about sleeping hours and the reason I used categories was because I wanted to know how many hours they slept on average daily. Should I still have made it a continuous variable?

Comment: Yes, you should record the actual number of hours slept, not a category

Comment: See also: [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606118/can-i-use-kruskal-wallis-test-for-dependent-and-fixed-ordinal-variables/606147](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606118/can-i-use-kruskal-wallis-test-for-dependent-and-fixed-ordinal-variables/606147)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure that the crudely categorized versions of those two measurements are all that were collected.   Then don't use a method such as Pearson's $\chi^2$ that ignores the ordinal nature of the variables.  Consider a rank correlation method such as Goodman-Kruskal $\gamma$ or one of the Kendall $\tau$s.  Be sure to quantify the degree of association and to downplay statistical "significance" which actually means quite little.  Also consider computing a confidence interval for the rank correlation measure to show sample size limitations.

Comment: Thank you sir. Since I am treating my variables asymmetrically should I use a somer's D instead of goodman kruskal or kendall tests?

Comment: It all depends which ties you want to ignore