# Can I use Kruskal-Wallis test for dependent but also independent ordinal variables?

Tags: ordinal-data, kruskal-wallis-test

Can I use the Kruskal-Wallis test for data that has two columns of ordinal data (scales)? The first column has respondents' subjective evaluations of the product's price (dependent variable) on a scale 1=cheap to 5=expensive, and the other is the respondents' economic situation evaluated on a scale excellent to bad(independent variable).
Both scales are 5-point.
the n=185

[image: data]

Comment: Could you provide some additional information? It would be helpful, for example, to share the tables/data you mentioned directly here.

Comment: What exactly is the hypothesis that you are trying to test?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva The H1 should test whether there is a statistically significant difference between the economical situation and price evaluation at least in between two eco. sit groups. I am clueless about what I can test with this type of data. I would appreciate any help regarding the test and hypothesis.

Comment: The answer to this question might help you https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538835/can-i-use-chi-square-for-two-ordinal-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to treat the ordinal [edit: ***independent***] variable as nominal categorical and stick with the Kruskal-Wallis test.

Similar tests that treat the independent variable as ordinal in nature are the Jonckheere–Terpstra and Cuzick tests.

You might also look at the association of the two variables with tests like the linear-by-linear test (ordinal chi-square) or Kendall's *tau* (*tau*-b since both variables have the same number of levels will work fine, or *tau*-c).  Practically speaking, Spearman correlation will also work fine as long as the implementation accounts for tied values.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The easiest approach for me would be to use KW, but I will try to look into other mentioned tests. Thank you!